Assign static IP address (outbound traffic) for every pod in EKS cluster
I have my software running in EKS cluster, where every node can fit up to 5 pods. The software uses multiple accounts on 3rd-party service which requires IP whitelisting. I have separate manifest files for every pod and all the pods should use unique IPs (so I can whitelist them). What options do I have to implement such system? Preferably I want to specify Elastic IP in YAML file, so a pod will use it for outbound traffic.
I know that it's possible to set Elastic IP to a load balancer, but not sure what to do with outbound traffic. Should I create many NAT GWs?
